# Human entities in the loop are not loaded in the graphical interface

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-vision, cloud-document-ai

Currently I have my own processor in DocumentAI, I am making the request to HITL but when I look at the review interface it loads the document but the entities do not appear and additionally it does not allow to make annotations.

I have tested HITL consumption and the document loads in the Human in the loop interface, but the entities do not appear.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible reasons why the human entities in the loop are not loaded in the graphical interface:

- The HITL job is not yet complete. It can take some time for HITL to process the document and load the entities.
- The HITL job is in a failed state. Check the HITL job status to see if there were any errors.
- The HITL job is using a custom processor that does not support entity extraction.
- The HITL job is using a pre-trained processor that is not trained to extract entities.

To troubleshoot the issue, you can try the following:

- Wait for the HITL job to complete.
- Check the HITL job status to see if there were any errors.
- Make sure that the HITL job is using a custom processor that supports entity extraction.
- Make sure that the HITL job is using a pre-trained processor that is trained to extract entities.

If you are still having problems, please contact Google Cloud support for assistance.

Here are some additional tips for troubleshooting HITL issues:

- Make sure that you are using the latest version of the DocumentAI API.
- Check the DocumentAI documentation for more information on HITL troubleshooting.
- Search the DocumentAI community forum for help from other users.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Syed
My processor is Custom Extractor

Comment: Hi Syed, When a custom extractor processor is created, two versions of the model are generated.
A generative AI type and a customized one, by default when the processor is pointed to, it has the generative AI version assigned to it.
Therefore it must be changed by configuration or by request. 
I have already solved